# Different log level for module in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import logging

logging.getLogger('socketIO-client').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(name)s:\t%(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger()

from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
```

I'd like to have DEBUG level for the script I'm working on and a different level INFO for the module socketIO_client.

Still ... the debug messages from the socketIO module keep coming. I tried different names, checked the right name in the module itself, different logger names ...

Problem is .. those debug lines are pretty long so that makes it difficult to see other debug messages. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the levvel setting line **after** the logger has been defined, ie:

```
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(name)s:\t%(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger()

from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
logging.getLogger('socketIO-client').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sounds fair but does not work. Same result: debug lines from socket module.